# Rails 4 Route "match" changes the CSS/JS base URL on template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm making a blog system for my Rails application and I'm stuck with this problem a while and don't know what's going on with my routes.

I installed a template for my app and all the css/js/images files from this template are in "public/" not in the assets folder. It was the only way I found to make the template working.

My blog system have this routes:
[image]

When I access "/blog" it serves the index view and it loads all the assets from "assets" and "public". But when I try to access "/blog/" or the matched route "/blog/category_slug/post_slug" rails tries to load the files from "public/" with this URL:
[image]

"base_url/blog/category_slug" and that's really weird!

I'm current using Rails 4.0.2. Any thoughts?

Comment: use get instead of match in rails 4. match is deprecated

Comment: @SamD it gives me the same result.

Comment: did you restart your app?

Comment: @SamD Yes, I did all the dumb stuff already.

Comment: I'm pretty sure match gives you errors in 4 as it is deprecated once you change it restart your app. if you could post your error log that would help.

Comment: @SamD I already changed to get and restarted my app, It's happening the same thing. When I visit any other page all the assets from the public folder loads properly, but when I access the matched route from the 'get' route my assets URLs instead of (Example: "css/bootstrap.css") are being replaced like this: "blog/category_slug/css/bootstrap.css" and then I get a Routing::Error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43952/discussion-between-sam-d-and-rafael-fragoso)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem adding a "/" before the path to the assets:

**From: "css/bootstrap.css"**

**To: "/css/bootstrap.css"**

I still don't know why this only happens in the blog controller, but that worked.
Thanks.